# Python: Efficient lookup by interval

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

I have a large lookup table where the key is an interval:

```
| min | max | value   |
|-----|-----|---------|
| 0   | 3   | "Hello" |
| 4   | 5   | "World" |
| 6   | 6   | "!"     |
| ... | ... | ...     |
```

The goal is to create a lookup structure `my_lookup` that returns a value for each integer, depending on the range the integer is in.
For example: `2 -> "Hello"`, `3 -> "Hello"`, `4 -> "World"`.

Here is an implementation that does what I want:

```
d = {
  (0, 3): "Hello",
  (4, 5): "World",
  (6, 6): "!"
}

def my_lookup(i: int) -> str:
  for key, value in d.items():
    if key[0] <= i <= key[1]:
      return value
```

But looping over all entries seems inefficient (the actual lookup table contains 400.000 lines). Is there a faster way?

Comment: Typically, you store the intervals in an [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).

Comment: Are the intervals guaranteed to be disjoint?

Comment: Yes, the intervals are disjoint. And there will be millions of lookups after the lookup table has been initialized ... so if sorting increases lookup efficiency, it would definitely be worth it.

Comment: To give you some background: The actual problem is to determine a user's country from his IP address on a web server.

Comment: Wait, so what are the actual intervals: IP address ranges? You probably want a Patricia trie, then, as the ranges are likely network prefixes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your intervals are sorted (in ascending order), you can use `bisect` module ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left)). The search is O(log n) instead of O(n):

```
min_lst = [0,       4,       6]
max_lst = [3,       5,       6]
values = ['Hello', 'World', '!']

import bisect

val = 2

idx = bisect.bisect_left(max_lst, val)
if idx < len(max_lst) and min_lst[idx] <= val <= max_lst[idx]:
    print('Value found ->', values[idx])
else:
    print('Value not found')
```

Prints:

```
Value found -> Hello
```